# Inverse transform of digamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $g$ be in $C_c^\infty(\bf R)$, and $h$ its Fourier transform. There is the following equation:

\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty}h(r)\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(1+ir)dr=&-\gamma g(0)+\int^\infty_0\log(u)g'(u)du\notag\\
&+\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_{-\infty}g(u)du+\int^\infty_0\log\Big(\frac{\sinh(\frac{u}{2})}{\frac{u}{2}}\Big)g'(u)du.\notag
\end{align}

I would like to know how to derive this so I can use it at other arguments of $\Gamma'/\Gamma$. (For which ones is it valid for?)

I know that for $z$ not a negative integer,
$$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+z}\Big)$$
so the first term $\gamma g(0)$ follows immediately. The remaining ones I do not know how to deal with.

Comment: you know that $\langle f, u \rangle = \langle \hat{f}, \hat{u} \rangle $ ? so did you try simply inverse Fourier transforming each term of the series for $\Gamma'/\Gamma(z)$, rearranging, integrating by part, and showing by dominated convergence that it gives your formula ?

Comment: you might also use $\displaystyle \psi(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{e^{-st}}{1 - e^{-t}}\right)\,dt$ for $Re(s) > 0$